# android invasive advertising screen from installed app, how to replicate that?

Tags: android, notifications, screen, ads

I installed an app on my android phone to safe lock certain apps with a password. Since I installed it, sometimes, regardless what i'm doing on the phone/which app i'm using, a full size screen with advertising appears and I have to click an "X" to close it or press back/home button.
(Can be that this screen appears randomly only when I digited a password to unlock an app therefore the safe lock app was active let's say, not sure.)

I was anyway wondering what sort of code is used for this? Anyone?

I'd need it for a less despicable cause: in order to show a transparent view with alertdialog when my timer is up and the app is closed, to imitate the original builtin countdown timer.

Comment: You should probably report that app on the play store, you mustn't just show ads out of the blue

Comment: I see, so is illegal basically.. I wondered how could be accepted indeed, as sometimes advs had loud music too and has been annoying twice while in public with phone on silent mode :(. as I just edited I'd need it to replicate the original built-in countdown timer alert that shows up regardless what you doing on the phone tho, if anyone know how to do it prob my use of it would be accepted by play store? also anyone know another legal way to obtain that sort of timer alert? thanks

Comment: check out `AlarmManager` to register an intent

Comment: @David Medenjak thanks, i'm trying AlarmManager but it doesn't seem to allow for an alert dialog external to the app, on alarm onReceive(), i mean when i'm on main phone menu for instance i'd like to get an alert dialog from the alarm